# How to create flutter project only for only Android and iOS even if web support is enabled?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to create flutter project targeted to only android and IOS. But my web support is enabled in flutter.
I don't want to go back to stable channel to do that. Anyone can help me out in doing this in beta channel itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable web support in `flutter config`. use `flutter config --no-enable-web` to disable and `flutter config --enable-web` to enable. There are several other options as well which you can explore by running `flutter config`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Disable platforms in all projects

`flutter config --no-enable-[platform-name]`, eg: `flutter config --no-enable-web`.

#### Disable platforms in a specific project

New project: `flutter create --platform ios,android`

Existing project: Edit the `<project-root>/.metadata` file, delete unwanted platforms under `migration -> platforms`. Only leave `root` and platforms you need. I can't find this documented anywhere so the method can stop working anytime, as of Feb. 2023 it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
flutter create --platforms ios,android your_project_name
```